# A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am using spring mvc(not maven),my problem is that tomcat(8.0) stops while deploying.
With out deploying my project i tried to start tomcat via eclipse,it works successfully.

My error console

```
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVCBasic' did not find a matching property.
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.23.0
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.13.0-55-generic
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          i386
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b14
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/vishnum/workshop/projects/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/vishnum/workshop/tools/Apachetomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.23
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/vishnum/workshop/projects/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/vishnum/workshop/tools/Apachetomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.23
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/vishnum/workshop/projects/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/vishnum/workshop/tools/Apachetomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/endorsed
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 676 ms
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCBasic]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCBasic]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:303)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:479)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 21, 2015 12:24:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:303)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:479)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

These are the library files,i am using

```
com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.fileupload-1.2.0.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar
com.springsource.org.codehaus.jackson.mapper-1.0.0.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
jmxtools-1.2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.6.release.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring.web.servlet-3.1.1.jar
```

I added "commons-logging-1.1.2.jar" as specified in some tutorial,but it wont works.

My controller class is shown below.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.indocosmo.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

     @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

//   @Override
//      public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
//              DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
//          configurer.enable();
//      }    
     @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }

      @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.56:3306/pmsdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8");
            dataSource.setUsername("pmsuser");
            dataSource.setPassword("pmspw");

            return dataSource;
        }
     @Bean
        public Userdao getContactDAO() {
            return new Userdaoimplementation(getDataSource());
        }


}
```

I cannot locate what is happening,Can any one please help me any help will be highly appreciable...

Comment: Give permission to tomcat folder i.e tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/

Comment: Use compatible version of jars in your application. These jars added twice in your application library. org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar, org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M2.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar,

Comment: You are mixing jars from several spring versions, never mix versions of any framework. You are mixing 3.0.1.RELEASE, 3.0.1.M@, 3.0.6, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, you also have multiple commons-logging jars on your classpath. Basically your setup is a mess, fix your paths, I strongly suggest using something like maven to manave your files instead of trying to get the ones you need by yourself. Saves you a lot of trouble...